# Accessing BDB file fails on linux using Perl

Tags: linux, perl, file, solaris, berkeley-db

I have a program that reads a very large data file from Berkeley DB [ which is mounted on a SAN Storage ]. This works perfectly fine on a solaris machine using perl5.6.0 version.

However, the same program returns fewer values read from the same file on a linux machine. Is this a problem with the size of the data file?

Any pointers to solve this mystery are welcome.

Thanks,
Shobha Deepthi

**edit** to include Shobha's reproducer (from comments):

```
#!/usr/cisco/bin/perl5.6
use strict;
use DB_File qw($DB_HASH);
my $db_file = "/vws/aak/qddts/data/value_cache/To-be-fixed";
my $db_ref;
my %db;

if (tie(%db, 'DB_File', $db_file, O_RDONLY, 0444, $DB_HASH)) {
    $db_ref = \%db;
    print Dumper($db_ref);
}
1;
```

Comment: How large is "very large"? What interface are you using to access BDB? Are your Perl and BDB libraries 64bit or 32bit? Do even _small_ databases work as you expect? Can you post a small example that will show the problem?

Comment: have you taken into consideration that your Solaris box is likely [big endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) and your Linux box is likely [little endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)?

Comment: @sarnold

File is 159 MB. But it has keys more than 30,000. It perfectly works for small files with less number of records.
 It does not throw any error, but returns undef for all the keys that I try to access after 12,000 records.
#!/usr/cisco/bin/perl5.6
use strict;

use DB_File qw($DB_HASH);
my $db_file = "/vws/aak/qddts/data/value_cache/To-be-fixed";
my $db_ref;
my %db;
if (tie(%db, 'DB_File', $db_file, O_RDONLY, 0444, $DB_HASH)) {
        $db_ref = \%db;
        print Dumper($db_ref);
}
1;
</pre>

Comment: In the above code, it prints both keys and values on Solaris, but on Linux after say 12,000 entries it prints only keys and values as undef.

Comment: If Endianness is the problem, dont you think it should fail for all the cases?

Comment: What version of BerkeleyDB is installed on the Solaris machine? And the Linux box?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a filesystem issue to me. What is your fstype? Oh, and what versions / distros / archs are your OSs?

Things to check:

- Does the script work on linux when the file is on local storage?
- Are your versions of Perl, BDB and DB_File the same across both systems?

[yet another edit] I would also run a strace on your script in linux to see if there's anything strange happening around record 12,000

Comment: Hi...regenerating this file helped solve the issue. I did not try copying it to a local workspace and run my script.

Comment: ah good. I did some quick math and (assuming a linear file structure), 12,000 records of 30,000 at 160Mb was about 64Mb... that's a sort of a suspicious value to me, and sounded like buffering or a driver implementation failure. I've had cases in the past where flaky linux drivers for LUNs have resulted in similar issues...

Comment: Unfortunately regenerating the file does not seem to work anymore. How did you resolve the issue?

Comment: well, I don't think the problems I've seen and your problems are exactly the same. I would check to see if the script works when the file is on local storage. I would also be confirming the versions of BDB, DB::File and Perl are the same on your solaris and linux box.